# Turning off reminders when creating a new Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar

When creating a new Google Calendar event, I always turn off those reminders (there are two of them). Since GCalendar is always open in a side window, I don't need them.

**Is there a way to *disable them* so when you're creating a new event, they're already turned off?**

*Seems like a simple thing, but I can't find anything that would do that in Settings.*

Answer (score 6):

In Calendar Settings, goto "Calendars" tab and you will see a list of your calendars.

For each one, select "Notifications" and you will see the default settings for "event reminders".

Simply click the small "remove" link beside each reminder, then save.